# The name 'yonet' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, class

I have an asp.net project and I have a few clases in App_Code folder.

But I got this error "**The name 'yonet' does not exist in the current context"**

I didnt use namespace none of them.It was working but now doesnt work.

I tried to add namespace but nothing change.

Why I cant access my classes ?

Comment: Where is `yonet` defined? Is it a public class?

Comment: Did you upgrade from a *Web Site* to a *Web Application*?

Comment: @Oded yes. public class yonet {...}

Comment: And it is defined... where?

Comment: @just.another.programmer I created a new web application and added class.then copied methods from other project

Comment: @Oded App_Code/BusinessLogic/yonet.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your classes out of `App_Code` and it should work fine.

A *Web Site* uses the `App_Code` folder to [automatically compile classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at run time, effectively allowing you to share code .

A *Web Application* does not (and should not) use the `App_Code` folder as it is precompiled before being published.  VS will *[ignore all code](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.co.il/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)* in the `App_Code` folder at build time in  *Web Application*.

Comment: I created a new folder named Classes and moved all classes to new folder and then rebuilt solution.Nothing change.Same error :S

Comment: about build action ? Build action must be changed content to compile ?

Comment: Yes, change the build action to compile.